# zlib incorrect data check macbook m1 pro 2021

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm unable to install dependencies on my project. I tried different versions of Node and NPM without success.

- `Node v14.16.1 NPM v6.14.16`
- `Node v14.19.0 NPM v6.14.16`
- `Node v16.14.0 NPM v8.5.3`

In my windows pc everything works fine with Node v14.16.1 and NPM v6.14.16. But in my new Macbook M1 Pro 2021 i didn't find a way to install dependencies.

This is the error:

## Error

```
npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check
```

## Log

```
2232 verbose stack ZlibError: zlib: incorrect data check
2232 verbose stack     at Unzip.write (/Users/coder/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:147:22)
2232 verbose stack     at Object.write (/Users/coder/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:313:19)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:400:28)
2232 verbose stack     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
2232 verbose stack     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Transform.push (internal/streams/transform.js:166:32)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.afterTransform (internal/streams/transform.js:101:10)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough._transform (internal/streams/passthrough.js:46:3)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Transform._read (internal/streams/transform.js:205:10)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Transform._write (internal/streams/transform.js:193:12)
2232 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
2232 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:400:28)
2233 verbose cwd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApplication
2234 verbose Darwin 21.0.1
2235 verbose argv "/Users/coder/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node" "/Users/coder/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/npm" "install"
2236 verbose node v14.19.0
2237 verbose npm  v6.14.16
2238 error code Z_DATA_ERROR
2239 error errno -3
2240 error zlib: incorrect data check
2241 verbose exit [ -3, true ]
```

Comment: You're just getting some incorrect data while trying to unzip a package; try cleaning the npm cache and retrying.

Comment: @AKX i tried also to clean cache with `npm cache clean --force` but the error persist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Z\_DATA\_ERROR, ERRNO -3, zlib: incorrect data check, MBA M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793334/z-data-error-errno-3-zlib-incorrect-data-check-mba-m1)